# How do I keep track of marking work in my own mark procedure for boehm GC and what is the purpose of 'env'

Tags: boehm-gc

How do I keep track of how much marking work I've done when implementing my own mark procedure?  I am working to use the Boehm Weiser Garbage Collector in precise mode.  I need to implement my own mark procedures.  For large objects like vectors that contain lots of pointers - the `gc_mark.h` header file says that I should break the work up into smaller pieces and push the object whose pointers I'm marking back onto the stack to continue marking later.  I can add a `size_t work_to_do` field to the object and use that - but I see the `env` argument that is passed to the GC_mark_proc. Is the `env` argument meant to store the amount of work done?

```
typedef struct GC_ms_entry * (*GC_mark_proc)(GC_word * /* addr */,
                                struct GC_ms_entry * /* mark_stack_ptr */,
                                struct GC_ms_entry * /* mark_stack_limit */,
                                GC_word /* env */);
```

The `env` value is set when the kind of the object is defined with `GC_new_kind` and `GC_MAKE_PROC` - after that there doesn't appear to be a mechanism to update it. This makes me think that `env` is not what I'm looking for.   If not - what is the purpose of `env`?